# How to display all the value from database in a JComboBox?

Tags: java

This code only display only one va, and repeat many times.
Hope someone can help me.
Thanks a lot.

```
private void originComboBox() {

        scheControl = new ScheduleControl();
        Schedule schedule = scheControl.getRecord();
        String origin = schedule.getDeparture();

        for(int i = 0; i < origin.length(); i++){
            originCB.addItem(origin);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: From the code you are adding the origin string as many times as it's length. You need to update the origin string.

Comment: You are retrieving a single ``String`` value from some ``Schedule`` object. You have to find a way to access "all the value" from your data model.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same origin each time. Shouln't it be origin[i] ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < origin.length(); i++){
    originCB.addItem(origin[i]);
}
```

Comment: ``origin`` is a ``String``. ``origin[i]`` is not gonna work.

Answer (score 1):

```
String origin = schedule.getDeparture();
```

- Your getting single string only.
- you have to get array of values. Do
- the modification than you will get result as you need. you can use
- for-each loop to check the values of array.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
 for(int i = 0; i < origin.length(); i++){
    originCB.addItem(origin[i]);
}
```

where origin should be Array .

```
    String origin[]={"A","B","C"};
```

Comment: ``origin`` is a ``String``. ``origin[i]`` is not gonna work. Also you cannot redeclare origin as an array since it comes from some getter. And i highly doubt that adding each character to the combobox is what the OP wants.